# Symfony2 Doctrine: ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony2 project I have the following query in my **ProductRepository.php**:

```
$dateNow = new \DateTime();
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->update('MyBundle\Products', 'p')
            ->set('p.published', $dateNow)
            ->getQuery();

$query->execute();
```

**ProductEntity.php:**

```
 /**
     * Set published
     *
     * @param \DateTime $published
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPublished($published)
    {
        $this->published = $published;

        return $this;
    }
```

ERROR:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

In other posts I already read something about toString methods that need to be integrated, but I don't know where to implement it...

Comment: Could you show the mapping of published field in ProductEntity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using parameters in your `QueryBuilder`:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->update('MyBundle\Products', 'p')
        ->set('p.published', ':dateNow')
        ->setParameter('dateNow', $dateNow)
        ->getQuery();
```